# how do i add active class to individual component which is mapped in react on hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add active class to a an individual component which is mapped.
i want to do something like when i hover over a component for example the first component then it only adds class to the component only and not every component that have been mapped in the render method.
i tried using the onMouseEnter but it seems to add active class to every component

```
    this.state = {
            projects: [
                {
                    type: 'react',
                    source: quoteMachine,
                    name: 'Quote Machine'
                    
                },
                {
                    type: 'react',
                    source: markup,
                    name: 'Markup Text'
                },
                {
                    type: 'react',
                    source: drumMachine,
                    name: 'Drum Machine'
                },
                {
                    type: 'react',
                    source: calculator,
                    name: 'Calculator'
                },
                {
                    type: 'react',
                    source: pomodoro,
                    name: 'Pomodoro Clock'
                },
                {
                    type: 'htmlCss',
                    source: tribute,
                    name: 'Tribute Page'
                },
                {
                    type: 'htmlCss',
                    source: survey,
                    name: 'Survey Form'
                },
                {
                    type: 'htmlCss',
                    source: landingPage,
                    name: 'Product Landing Page'
                },
                {
                    type: 'htmlCss',
                    source: documentation,
                    name: 'Javascript documentation'
                },
                

            ],
            currentProjects: [],
        }
```

this is the render method

```
    render() {

        let projx = this.state.currentProjects.map((proj, index) => {
            return (
                <Project 
                    key={index} 
                    source={proj.source} 
                    name={proj.name} alt={proj.name} 
                />
            )
        })

        return (
            <div className='projects'>
                <h2>Projects</h2>
                <div className='project-btns'>
                    <button className='project-btn' id='all' onClick={this.allProjects}>ALL</button>
                    <button className='project-btn' id='htmlCss' onClick={this.htmlCssProjects}>HTML/CSS</button>
                    <button className='project-btn' id='react' onClick={this.reactProjects}>REACT</button>
                </div>
                <div className='display'>
                <div className='project'>
                    {projx}
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement logic like below into your Project component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Project() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsActive(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsActive(false)}
        className={isActive ? 'active' : null}
    >
      //Your code...
    </div>
  );
}

export default Project;
```

For Class Component:

```
class Project extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isActive: false
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div
                onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({isActive: true})}
                onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({isActive: false})}
                className={this.state.isActive ? 'active' : null}
            >
            //Your code...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```